# How to change the keybroad language in phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am very new to phonegap development and I'm working on a phonegap-based program. When I use input, the keyboard always shows up with <kbd>Next</kbd>, <kbd>Prev</kbd> and <kbd>Done</kbd>. After some searching, I have determined that these three buttons are not removable. So now I wonder if I can change these buttons to local language, such as Chinese.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all guys, finally I found how to slove this problem. JUST add a language resource in the localizations of the project in the xcode. So the keyboard in the phonegap app can fit the language that you set in your device.

In my case, I add chinese language resource, and in the phonegap app the keyboard can display "Next","Prev","Done" in chinese.

Answer (score 0):

The language of buttons on a keyboard probably depends on the language that has been set for the whole the device. I don't think you can change it via PhoneGap

Comment: I set my device to Chinese, but the keyboard still comes in English...I have work on this for days, but still no solution to slove this problem.

Comment: Sorry, not the language of the device but the keyboard of the device. You can have a device in chinese and still have a keyboard in english. You need to go under Settings > General > Keyboard > International (translated from french but it should be something like that) to add a new keyboard.

Comment: @TDeBailleul my keyboard is set to English UK but the buttons are in German lol.... see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245093/wrong-language-on-native-controls-ios-html5-cordova-app