# Wrong language on native controls iOS HTML5 & Cordova app

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I built an application for Android/iOS using HTML5 & Cordova 2.9.

I have a weird issue on iOS only: each time a native control is shown, (for example when an `<input>` tag is focused, or a `<select>` is tapped), the "action" buttons are labelled in German language, despite the device language is set to English.

For example, the "Done" label becomes "Fertig".

I am using Xcode5 and targeting for iOS7 only. Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can try specifying language like `<html lang="en">`

Comment: @bhargavg: That doesn't solve it :-( Has anyone an idea how to fix this? Very annoying especially for the "add event"-dialogs.